# Using gmock Matchers to set std::function as method argument inside EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

Trying to unit test private callback method of a class

```
class MyClass{
public:
 MyClass(Component& component) : component(component) {};
 void Init();
private:
 void callback();
 Component component;
}

void MyClass::callback(const std::string& text)
{
...
}
```

Callback is registered in public Init method using component member (component.register() method) which I can mock.

```
void MyClass::Init(){
   auto cb = std::bind(&MyClass::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1);
   connection = component.register(ESomeType::MyType, std::move(cb));
}

MOCK_METHOD2(register, boost::signals2::connection(ESomeType, std::function<void(const std::string&)>));
```

As suggested here
[How to unit test the std::bind function using gtest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591112/how-to-unit-test-the-stdbind-function-using-gtest)
I want to EXPECT_CALL of a component.register() function and store passed std::function<> argument in unit test local variable using SaveArg.
Then using that variable I should be able to call callback for testing purposes.

As component.register() is overloaded function I need to pass exact argument types to EXPECT_CALL using Matchers to avoid ambiguity.

Unfortunately, having problems with setting Matcher type.

Current test code:

```
ComponentMock component;
MyClass testClass(component);

std::function <void(const std::string& text)> componentCallback;

EXPECT_CALL(component, register(Matcher<ESomeType>(ESomeType::MyType),
                          Matcher< void(const std::string& text) >(componentCallback)))
                          .WillOnce(testing::SaveArg<1>(&componentCallback;);

testClass.init();

testClass.componentCallback( ... );
```

Is the approach correct in the first place? If yes, could you help me with following error:

```
In file included from gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:43:0, gmock.h:61, ComponentMock.hpp:16, Test.cpp:18:
In member function 'void Test_initialize()':
Test.cpp: error: no matching function for call to 'testing::Matcher<void(const std::basic_string<char>&)>::Matcher(std::function<void(const std::basic_string<char>&)>&)'
                                  Matcher< void(const std::string& string) >(componentCallback)));
                                                                                        ^
...
gmock-matchers.h:3747:1: note: candidate: testing::Matcher<T>::Matcher(T) [with T = void(const std::basic_string<char>&)]
 Matcher<T>::Matcher(T value) { *this = Eq(value); }
 ^~~~~~~~~~
gmock-matchers.h:3747:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::function<void(const std::basic_string<char>&)>' to 'void (*)(const std::basic_string<char>&)'
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is generally the right approach, but there are a couple of problems with  the code you've posted.  Firstly, the type you've specified for the `Matcher` is incorrect (you forgot `std::function`).  Secondly, `std::function` does not provide an appropriate equality operator, so you will have to use `::testing::An` instead of `::testing::Matcher`.

Fixing these problems, the test body should looking something like the following:

```
ComponentMock component;
MyClass testClass(component);

std::function <void(const std::string& text)> componentCallback;

EXPECT_CALL(component, register(Matcher<ESomeType>(ESomeType::MyType),
                          An< std::function<void(const std::string& text)>>()))
                          .WillOnce(testing::SaveArg<1>(&componentCallback;);

testClass.init();

testClass.componentCallback( ... );
```

As an aside, avoid using `register` as the name of a function.